# Not able to install gems as non-root user

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, rubygems

I have RVM installed, it was installed as root.  The permissions are:

```
drwxrwsr-x 23 root rvm   4096 2011-09-17 15:22 rvm
```

Here is an example of my trying to install a gem as sudo:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-2-15-243:/usr/local/rvm$ sudo gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.0.18
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.0.18...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.0.18...

ubuntu@ip-10-2-15-243:/usr/local/rvm$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rake (0.9.2)
```

The strange thing is that if I "sudo su -" and then install the gem as root, it works.  Is it a problem with how ubuntu is listed in the sudoers file?

```
ubuntu  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

I did edit sudoers with VIM, and it told me to use VISUDO so I'm not sure if that created a problem.

Comment: What does it look like when it fails?

Comment: there is no fail text, it says it installs but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `rvmsudo` instead of `sudo`.

If this is in the context of a chef run, you can use this resource:

```
execute "gem-install-bundler" do
  user "root"
  command <<-COMMAND
    bash -c '
      source {{{/path/to/rvm}}}
      rvm use {{{ruby-version}}}
      gem install bundler
    '
  COMMAND
end
```

Comment: That works when I try it by command line, but not when chef runs it.  It gives me an error that rvmsudo was not found.  Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Actually when I point to it by its path it runs but still doesn't install.  So rvmsudo works when logged in to the server, but not when it's run by chef..

Comment: This didn't work with chef..?  It's still having the same issue where it says it has installed bundler but it hasn't.

Comment: I think the problem was that I installed rvm with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

The RVM environment is probably not loaded by sudo.

Try running:

```
sudo -i gem install bundler
```

-i is : "simulate initial login"

Sorry but I can not verify it by myself at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this worked for me. It turns out that all other methods installed into the global gemset, which is why the command returns without an error

```
script 'bundle gems' do
  user 'root'
  code <<-EOH
    . "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
    cd /your/directory
    rvm rvmrc trust
    BUNDLE_WITHOUT=test bundle install
    exit $?
  EOH
  interpreter 'bash'
end
```